# Is there way to block user for accessing all site, not only wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, authentication, mod-security

Im using code from [this article](http://wpsecure.net/2012/01/using-mod_security-2-with-wordpress/), worked perfect, but i want to block access for entire site, not only for one page, is there any available method?

Using Ubuntu, php7, mod-security2.

Code:

```
<Locationmatch "/wp-login.php">
# Setup brute force detection.
# React if block flag has been set.
SecRule user:bf_block "@gt 0" "deny,status:401,log,id:5000135,msg:'ip address blocked for 5 minutes, more than 10 login attempts in 3 minutes.'"
# Setup Tracking. On a successful login, a 302 redirect is performed, a 200 indicates login failed.
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^302" "phase:5,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0,id:5000136"
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" "phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,deprecatevar:ip.bf_counter=1/180,id:5000137"
SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 10" "t:none,setvar:user.bf_block=1,expirevar:user.bf_block=300,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
</Locationmatch>
```

When any site user try to log in 10 times in 3 minutes with wrong credentials mod-security block access for this user(by IP) and only for this page(sitename/wp-login.php), but i need to ban for entire site. Is there way to make this via this rule and modsec without db/.htaccess and any other features?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I did that once in school - blocked the IP from access due to bruteforce, which meant that nobody on that WiFi could get in anymore (including me) :) - presented it as "no-bullshit-security"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Stender, but i need to block some IP in some situation(when he trying to access wp-admin with wrong credentials couple times)

Answer (score 1):

You could a plugin like limit login attempts, which would handle tracking failed logins, and would manage the IP's blocked. But since the plugin would only block future logins, you could add a basic function that harnesses the plugin to block access to the front end.

For example, with the Limit Login Attempts plugin installed, add the below code into functions.php - and made any changes you'd like.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'checkIfLockedOut');
function checkIfLockedOut(){
  if(function_exists('is_limit_login_ok')){
    $isNotLockedOut = is_limit_login_ok();
    if(!$isNotLockedOut){
      // you could wp_redirect here,
      // or do what you'd like.
      die('Sorry, you cannot access the site, you are locked out!');
    }
  }
}
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-login-attempts/

Comment: Tnx, but i need server side security, plugins not really powerfull method.

Comment: Have you looked into fail2ban?